# NSNumberFormatter not adding comma after decimal point

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to format a number, like this "123.123,00". I am using an `NSNumberFormatter`. 
The code is:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:12];

NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:result];

NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

But it does not seem to work. It gives result like this "266.482107256796". Any idea why the result is not "266.482,107,256,796"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping separator is used to separate digits in the integer part of a number and is *not used* in the fractional part. There's no built-in way to achieve this effect. If you only support decimal numbers, you could manually parse the formatted string and insert a comma after each 3 characters, starting with the decimal separator.

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString: formattedString];
NSUInteger decimalSeparatorLocation = [s rangeOfString: @"."].location;
if (decimalSeparatorLocation != NSNotFound) {
    for (NSUInteger i = decimalSeparatorLocation + 4; i + 1 < [s length]; i += 4)
        [s insertString: @"," atIndex: i];
}
```

Warning: this code is *typed on an iPad* (c).

Comment: I was not about is there any option to do this with built-in function.  I searched for hours. Thank you for confirming it and providing the code. It is converting 709.099639039865 to 709.09,96,39,03,98,65 but its not problem.It just need to change the increment value fro 3 to 4.`for (NSUInteger i = decimalSeparatorLocation + 4; i + 1 < [s length]; i += 4)`

Comment: @ZakirHyder Thanks for the correction. I edited the answer just because an answer should be correct in every regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
```

Comment: This does not solve this problem. It just replace . with , like 226.798225 to 226,798225. What I want is 226.798225 to 226.798,225